# How to link to external sites through youtube videos through annotations

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is there a way of linking to an external website through YouTube Videos, by creating annotations links?

That is, the link is embedded in the video. An example of what I want is given in [**this video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8XmdQjJ7BM). When viewed, there's a link in the bottom left corner.

It can be done with '**LinkedTube**' but it is not '**annotations**' style.

I searched the **Youtube API** also but didn't find anything related to annotations control.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube prohibits external links by default, but it is still possible to insert the external link. To do so you have two options:

1. Have a paid account
2. Buy some amount of ad

I think you have to contact youtube sales to discuss the details.

P.S.: We used external links [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_144671&feature=iv&index=62&list=PL629EC036F159E5DE&src_vid=3Gs7y5tCTeY&v=aGIPB19mIv0), check out the top right corner of the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you uploaded the video to your YouTube account.

In settings, you'll enter the link and text to be displayed when your video plays.

There are a few tutorials on YouTube that show exactly what steps to do, like [**this one**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbIhWvlQ388).